# How can I use the correct manner of English sentence?

Tags: grammar

is it possible to say the following as a statement or adage ? And if not what **manner** can I use?

> **the beaten** takes his rights from **the hitter**.

-I mean the word "beaten" as who was hit.
-(I mean the word "hitter" as who hit some one) is it possible to use them in this way, "the participle" as a subject and "the verb agent" as an object?

I wonder if this manner exists in English.

Comment: Grammatically, the sentence looks correct, but the idea of "takes his rights" is an alien concept in English speaking countries: you will need to explain exactly what you mean. Also, why is the second a noun derived from a different verb? Why not use "from the beater"?

Comment: @JavaLatte 'but the idea of "takes his rights" is an alien concept in English speaking countries' - I'd say it's an *essential* concept in at least some English speaking countries ("give me your tired, your poor, your huddling masses yearning to break free", anyone?). It's not a common English *phrase*, though.

Comment: the problem is that "beat" means "hit" and means "overcome" so I intended to use two different word to clarify that I mean "hit" not "overcome". but as for "takes his rights" is possible to say "gets his rights" instead ? if not, what can I say then?

Comment: Using "beaten"/"beater" in this context would make the sentence flow nicer and wouldn't really be ambiguous. The problem is that I'm not sure what you want to imply by "takes his rights" - is it describing the situation where the oppressed fight against the oppressor and take their rights *back*, or is it describing the situation where the oppressed *receive* their rights from the oppressor, ie. the oppressor is the one who decides what rights they have?

Comment: it is describing the situation where the oppressed receive their rights from the oppressor . it may happen some day and by some manner. and how I clear the ambiguity happened here? do you have a clue please?

Comment: I'd use "to receive" ("the beaten receives his rights from the beater"), it makes it clearer that the rights are bestowed by the one who's doing the beating rather than taken by the one who's beaten. That said, I wouldn't make it an *adage* in my life, as it carries some rather unpleasant connotations...

Comment: so would you say the two sentences that carry the both meanings? and reassure me if it's correct manner in English, please.

Comment: They're all correct English sentences (although not idiomatic). And I'd say your sentence in the OP can carry both meanings, while using *to receive* is unlikely to carry the "fighting for power" meaning.

Comment: I'm sorry, would you please give me two idiomatic sentences of the both situations?

Answer (score 1):

> the beaten takes his rights from the hitter.

This sort of makes sense - there are other adages and quotes constructed in a similar way. For example, "*The most potent weapon of the **oppressor** is the mind of the **oppressed***".

What doesn't make sense to me is why you would use "hitter", and not "beater" when you are referring to the person they hit as "the beaten"? It would make more sense and be more in keeping with similar sayings and adages if you said:

> The beaten takes his rights from the beater.

---

As an aside, I am confused as to what you mean by this. If you mean that beating someone takes away their rights, perhaps it should be "the beater takes away the rights of the beaten"?

Comment: all of your questions are in the former comments and have been responded.